# Viewport-responsive div dimensions and font size?

Tags: css

I'm working on a website over here:

[venuslabs.org](http://venuslabs.org/staging/)

Some of the tabs, such as "Technology Details (pdf)" and "Venus Needs Advocates (Take Part!)" create a number of subwindows in the middle.  Their sizes are based on em, so that they scale properly if the user changes their font size / zoom level (as I understand is "best practices" today).

The way they are looks fine... most of the time.  But when viewed on a cell phone in horizontal (not vertical) layout, they're just too big and overlap the top bar.  So it appears that the current layout is fine down to a certain height, but below that height I need to have the font size scale linearly with page height (with the subwindows scaling along with the font size).

Obviously I could do that with javascript, but I know you're supposed to do things in pure CSS where possible.  What would be the recommended approach?  I've been trying a number of things and none have really played out.

Comment: You could use something like `@media (orientation: landscape) { ... }` and add some CSS inside of that.  I could get more specific in an answer, but how far do you want to go in weird-aspect-ratio support?  For example: a Nexus 5X landscape mode with the URL bar and keyboard should be supported? http://i.imgur.com/7ajCQ0y.png  What about 1280x400px ?

Comment: Thanks for that, but I don't think that's quite right. I mean, a browser window is typically also landscape, but has no need at all to shrink its icons.  It's more of an issue of maximum height... in em, I suppose?  Maybe I should just play around with @media for a while and see if anything looks good....

Comment: It isn't just the height.  For example 1300px wide by 400px high is acceptable (in my opinion), but 700px wide by 400px high is not.  You could look into aspect ratio media query: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#aspect-ratio  You can also combine media queries, example: `@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) and (max-width: 700px)`